# wkhtmltopdf always using default sans-serif font

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using a Django wrapper with wkhtmltopdf however I'm having the problem that regardless of the fonts I use in my CSS it always just shows a default sans-serif font. It works locally and also works on the server when I just generate the HTML without converting it to the PDF.

[This](http://grab.by/FBcq) is how it shows on the server in the PDF and [this](http://grab.by/FBcA) is how it shows locally in the PDF. The font is a custom font base64 encoded, however it doesn't matter what font I use as none make a difference.

Is it something to do with the server setup?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What's the css you're applying to the text? wkhtmltopdf has some quirks, and apparently doesn't like fallbacks ([link](http://blog.gluga.com/2012/05/wkhtmltopdf-font-and-sizing-issues.html)). I was observing something similar and finally got a serif font (closest I could get to Times New Roman w/o downloading) by doing

```
font-family: "serif";
```

Answer (score 0):

`wkhtmltopdf` only includes fonts if it finds them in the local system in /usr/share/fonts

If you use fonts like `font-family: 'Liberation Sans';`  ,wkhtmltopdf will correctly include them in the PDF and render them as it should.

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still looking for a solution (in the current version of **wkHTMLtoPDF**). The solutions above didn´t solve my problem.

For me the correct solution was to add an `svg-font` for each font (font-type). **wkHTMLtoPDF** takes at least the `svg`. In my case, it always took the fallback font (Arial). I just converted each font and added it to my `font.scss`.

I hope this helps.